# Set status based on date differences

Tags: mysql

This is my input table (player table) with playerID and their played dates, I want this to be checked against milestone table, which has details on when player achieved his milestones
I want to check the milestone table against player table to see if they played within 60 days from the milestone date

- if they did not play they are a 60 day churner,  but if they returned back after 60 days then their status is a returner.
- If they did not return back at all then they are a 60 day churner
- If they played within 60 days after the milestone date then they are a active player

player table

| player-id | date_played |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/10/2022 |
| 1 | 1/11/2022 |
| 1 | 1/12/2022 |
| 1 | 1/13/2022 |
| 1 | 5/13/2022 |
| 1 | 5/14/2022 |
| 1 | 5/15/2022 |
| 2 | 1/15/2022 |
| 2 | 2/15/2022 |
| 3 | 8/15/2022 |
| 4 | 1/5/2022 |
| 4 | 5/5/2022 |

milestone table

| player_id | milestonedate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/13/2022 |
| 2 | 2/15/2022 |
| 3 | 8/15/2022 |
| 4 | 1/5/2022 |

My Output

| player_id | milestone_date | churn_status | player_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/13/2022 | 60 day churner | Returner |
| 2 | 2/15/2022 | 60 day churner | Churner |
| 3 | 8/15/2022 | 60 day churner | Churner |
| 4 | 1/5/2022 | Active player | Returner |

How can I achieve this

Comment: This kind of question is a lot easier to answer with a proper schema, as in `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. That you have M/D/YYYY formatted values is certainly something that stands out, as MySQL tends to conform to `YYYY-MM-DD` ISO style.

Comment: Where is the output for player 4 coming from? They're not in the input.

Comment: milestone_date + 60 days

Comment: now I see in your last bullet you say "within", so it's not exactly 60 days.

Comment: looking at your data I don't see why player 4 is "Active player"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are only interested in categorizing based on player rows (weird name for the table, since it seems to represent plays, not players) dated *after* the milestone date.

This is fairly straightforward (untested):

```
select m.player_id, m.milestone_date,
    case
        when min(p.date_played) <= m.milestone_date + interval 60 day then 'Active player'
        else '60 day churner'
    end churn_status,
    case
        when min(p.date_played) is not null then 'returner'
        else 'churner'
    end player_status
from milestone m
left join player p on p.player_id=m.player_id and p.date_played > m.milestone_date
group by m.player_id
```

This finds the minimum date played (if any) for player rows after the milestone date for each player, and uses that to determine the statuses.

Comment: the player status is returner is they play within 60 days after the milestone date.

Comment: <= 60 for active

Comment: edited for that.

Comment: and fixed an error

Comment: Can you please explain you case statements, Why MIN?

Comment: How can I change the condition if I want to reduce the 60 day window to 7-14 days? Those who left after reaching the milestone in 7-14 days

Comment: min because I am joining any player records for each milestone player id and returning one row per player id and checking the min date played to decide the statuses, using case

Comment: not sure what 7-14 days means; ignore any rows less than 7 days after milestone?  if not ignore them, do what with them?

Answer (score 0):

Use left joins to match plays within 60 days and after 60 days.

```
SELECT m.player_id, m.milestone_date, 
    IF(MAX(c.player_id IS NULL), '60 day churner', 'Active player') AS churn_status, 
    IF(MAX(r.player_id IS NULL), 'churner', 'returner') AS player_status
FROM milestone AS m
LEFT JOIN player AS c ON c.player_id = m.player_id AND c.date_played > m.milestone_date AND c.date_played <= DATE_ADD(m.milestone_date, INTERVAL 60 DAY)
LEFT JOIN player AS r ON c.player_id = m.player_id AND c.date_played > DATE_ADD(m.milestone_date, INTERVAL 60 DAY)
GROUP BY m.player_id
```

This joins with `player` twice. The first join gets all the rows where the play is between the mileston date and 60 days later. The second join gets all the rows where the play is after 60 days.

If there are no matches for either date relationships, that join will return a row where all the columns in `player` are `NULL`. The `IF()` conditions test whether each join contains those null values, and produces the appropriate result in that column.

Comment: can you explain the query please

Comment: I've added an explanation and also fixed some problems.